# Issuing with creating buttons using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I am trying to create a grid of images. This is related to some other questions I had, but I have since improved my code to clean it up, but now I am getting errors when I try to load the image paths.
The images are all stored in a folder called cardImages.
I know the issue lies somewhere in PhotoImage() but so far have been unable to figure it out.
Current output of the imageMaker function is: `./cardImages/red shaded circle1.gif`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from Deck import Deck


#nCards = deckOfSETs.getNumberOfCards()
# Create for loop to create all possible card combos 
#for i in range(nCards):
    #print(deckOfSETs.getCard(i).getFileName())

root = tk.Tk()

# Init a Deck
deckOfSETs = Deck()

# Utility Function
def imageMaker(deck, cardNum, rootPath = './cardImages/'):
    cardFile = deck.getCard(cardNum).getFileName()
    print(rootPath + cardFile)
    return PhotoImage(file = rootPath + cardFile)


# Build the grid iterating over rows and columns 
nRows = 4
nCols = 3
counter = 0
for r in range(nRows):
    for c in range(nCols):
        btn = tk.Button(padx=50, pady=50, image = imageMaker(deckOfSETs, counter))
        btn.grid(row = r, column=c)
        
        counter += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an output that I am currently getting
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhiyI.png)

And here is an example of what I want it to be [Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0hm.png)

Edit: I realized I probably left out an important piece of info. I have 2 classes that create the images and then put them into a 'deck' and shuffle them.
The output of my imageMaker funtion is: `./cardImages/red solid circle1.gif`

So it has everything I think it needs, but it doesn't actually show the image.

Comment: Can you share the `Deck.py` file? This makes it runnable, so we can see what happens.

Comment: You need to save a reference of the image for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating button in a for loop , but assigning in a single variable 'btn'.
This is not a good practice
change the code like below and check

```
nRows = 4
nCols = 3
counter = 0
def createButton():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    return Button(root,padx=50, pady=50, image = imageMaker(deckOfSETs, counter))

buttons=[[createButton() for c in range(nCols)] for r in range(nRows) ]
for r in range(nRows):
    for c in range(nCols):
        buttons[r][c].grid(row = r, column=c)
```

but i am not sure this is the problem